# Can you use JSF/Primefaces to update a JARs JFrame content?

Tags: java, jsf, jsf-2, primefaces, jframe

I'm designing an executable Java program that is going to behave similarly to a webpage, but there won't be internet. Everything will just be in a JFrame and the contents are going to be updated for simulate going to a new page on the site. Would it be possible to use JSF and Primefaces for this? I've only ever done JSF with a webpage and am not sure if I could use it for a JFrame type program. I realize I can't recompile, I'm just wondering if I can use xml style and JavaBeans with JSF in a JFrame rather than the internet and how to go about that.

Comment: I don't know any JSF implementation for swing applications.

Comment: Only if you forget the Swing part and can run an embedded servletcontainer like Jetty (basically, the client runs all by itself the whole webserver).

Comment: Sio should I just use java and forget about jsf for inner "webpages" for the jframe?

Comment: You're using Java anyways ;)
I cannot recommend JSF for local Java-Apps. Use Swing or JavaFX instead, they're much easier to handle when it comes to bi-directional events. (JSF and Ajax can get quite complex if you want it to be interactive)

Comment: @Zhedar: even more, there's absolutely nothing to "recommend" or whatsoever subjectively can be done. It's simply the wrong tool for the job. Just use the right tool for the job. It's indeed much harder to get down a nail using a screwdriver instead of a hammer.

Comment: @BalusC, so what is the right tool for the job? Simply using swing components and updating the according to whatever "page" it's on?

Comment: Go with Swing or try the new JavaFX if you want xml behaviour.